# Using php include function in html within php variable

Tags: php, html, include

i am doing something like this

```
   $some_var='<!DOCTYPE html>
              <head>
              <title>questions '.$suto.'</title>
              <meta charset="utf-8" />
              <meta name="description" content="question need to'. $suto.'">
              '. include ("header.php") .'
              <body>
```

There is more code below which is working that's why not posting here.

Everything works instead the include function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `include()` you can use `file_get_contents()` like,

```
$some_var='<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
            <title>questions '.$suto.'</title>
             <meta charset="utf-8" />
             <meta name="description" content="question need to'.$suto.'">'.file_get_contents("header.php").'
    <body>
```

`file_get_contents()` is a PHP function which is one of the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string.

`include()` will parse PHP code inside the included file. And `file_get_contents()` will return the content of the file. Here, you are storing the content to a string. So the `file_get_contents` is the right option.

Comment: ty jenz it works but why include function failed in this case

Comment: @sukhjitdhot..Sorry for the delay. Please check my updated answer for more details.

Comment: thanks jenz file-get-contents ("../header.php") is not working can you suggest how to select header from previous directory

Comment: If header.php resides in the folder below then ("../header.php") should work.

Comment: that's what exactly i hoped but it is not working for some reason.

Comment: Can you share your project folder structure?

Comment: Given header.php is a PHP file, this answer makers **absolutely no sense**

Answer (score 0):

You could use file-get-contents function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$some_var='<!DOCTYPE html>
           <head>
           <title>questions '.$suto.'</title>
           <meta charset="utf-8" />
           <meta name="description" content="question need to'. $suto.'">
           '. file-get-contents ("header.php") .'

           <body>';
```